# SQL Server Deadlock on Update primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I am having a weird issue and I am not sure how to address it correctly. I have 1 table that gets hit quite a bit and has started to produce deadlocks.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE object 
(
            id NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            type NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            subId NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            scheduleTime BIGINT NOT NULL,
            message NVARCHAR(MAX),
            status TINYINT,
            send_to NVARCHAR(255),
            owner NVARCHAR(255),
            date DATETIME,
            retry TINYINT,
            CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(id, type, subId, scheduleTime, send_to)
);
```

The two queries that clash are one update for claim query and one release query.

So my workers do this:

1. Update top X rows with the correct owner
2. Select the rows that now have the correct owner
3. Release the rows based on their key

Query A:

```
UPDATE TOP (?) object 
SET owner = ?, status = 2 
WHERE owner IS NULL 
  AND send_date <= ? 
  AND status = 1
```

Query B:

```
UPDATE object 
SET status = %s, 
    owner = NULL, 
    retry = retry + 1 
WHERE ( (%s) AND owner='%s');
```

So in short, query A:

- Update X rows and change the status + set the owner where owner is NULL and status is  1

Query B:

- Update all rows set status to > 2 and owner null where owner is NOT NULL and status is 2.

My question:

How do those 2 queries deadlock? They can by design never operate on the same row at the same time? They should not be deadlocking each other.

Some more information:

From my deadlock graph, I can see that SQLServer is taking out a PageLock. 
From the existing deadlocks I can see that it is at random which query is killed and rolled back.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and the Microsoft 4.2 JDBC driver

My questions:

1. How would I go about fixing this? I have 2 ideas:

1.1. Change Query A to do a SElect before hand, then use the Primary Key to update them instead. 
1.2. Change the query to take out a Rowlock specifically instead.

Is there a problem changing the lock to a rowlock? Any risk/performance issues that I would encounter?

2. Add retry logic on the application layer.
   I can catch the Exception and retry until it goes through. Not ideal since it is killing performance a bit.
3. Change the isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED
   Since my queries by design can never handle the same data, wouldn't it be OK to set the isolation level down?

Any help with this would be great. I am still struggling to understand how and why this is happening in the first place which is making it hard to come up with a plan for it.

Thanks,

Artur

Comment: Option 2 (try again) is the way to go.  Deadlocks are too unpredictable.

Comment: Are you using some transactions? Classical deadlock scenario is to begin transaction, select something from table, update records in same table - and do similar things on other connection. We avoid most problems with (updlock, rowlock) hints for select and (rowlock) for update - but exception handling is required anyway (SQL server escalates locks and places different locks on indexes etc etc).

Comment: I am not using specific transactions but letting the driver/db server do this on its own. All my queries are fairly easy so I didn't find it necessary. I will add exception handling regardless, but was thinking if there is a way to rewrite the queries to not deadlock in the first place. My claim process is: Update top X, select what is updated. But this happens in 2 transactions

Comment: I added an option 3 where I set the isolation level to read_uncommitted. Would that be a smart choice?

Comment: So in your transactions that deadlock, the one and only thing that is done within the transaction is changing that one table? Or are more things happening within the transaction, like reading/writing from other tables?

Comment: yes - there are no joins and no other operations being done. It is only updating  the table and setting owner,status and retry. That's all it does.

Comment: I have experienced deadlocks on simple select queries using SSMS.

Comment: Specify the table hint (TABLOCK) in the queries.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause even more deadlocks since now it's not only locking a page but the entire table, so every other transaction will fail?

Comment: @pandaadb, No.   A deadlock occurs when 2 processes both have locks that prevent each other from completing.   If you make the process grab a full table lock, then other processes can't get a lock at all, so no deadlock will occur.   At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: That would as well slow everything down though :/